# Can I compile and run HelloWorld.cpp in Visual Studio 2019 without creating a project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Can I compile and run `HelloWorld.cpp` in Visual Studio 2019 without a project?
I like writing 1-file utility programs that I improve iteratively, and find creating a project overkill.
This question was asked a couple of times about 10 years ago, and the answers were all workarounds.
Some suggested using Code::Block IDE instead.
I know the latest Visual Studio tries to be GitHub friendly, and not force a Visual Studio project mindset on all projects.  So, thought it would be worthwhile asking again.
StackOverflow warned I might get down-voted for this.  Ouch!  Still worth asking, because I'd really like to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Visual Studio command window (that  will have all the environment set for compiling the a C/C++ source) then use CL command to compile the source.

```
CL HelloWorld.CPP
```

FYI: truly speaking you may open any command window and then set the compiler environment variable. by running the following command may sent the env for x64 (change the vs install dir based on your system install location)

```
%comspec% /k "C:\VS2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```